# Failure uploading file to S3 from gitlab workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab, aws-cli

I'm trying to upload `workspace.yaml` to an S3 bucket only if it does not already exist there.

I am using this workflow named `gitlab-ci.yaml`:

```
  environment: dev
  variables:
    AWS_REGION: us-east-1
    WORKSPACEFILE_PATH: aws s3 ls s3://${BUCKET}/Workspace/config/workspace.yaml
  script:
    - PATH="./workspace.yaml"
    - echo "INFO - Searching Workspace in $WORKSPACEFILE_PATH"
    - |
      if [ "$WORKSPACEFILE_PATH" != "" ]; then
      - aws s3 cp ./workspace.yaml  s3://${BUCKET}/Workspace/config/workspace.yaml
        exit 0
      else
        echo "Not Uploaded"
      fi
```

Upload fails.

Comment: Add the error message. Looks like you are missing definition of environment variables required to access AWS from secrets.

Comment: It would be helpful if error details are provided!

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the `aws s3 ls s3://${BUCKET}/Workspace/config/workspace.yaml` with no variables used, if this works then use variables and test again, run the command from the command line and not the script to troubleshoot more easily.
2. Check you AWS S3 permissions on the bucket you are trying to copy a file to.
3. To check if a string is empty, you could use `[-z "$WORKSPACEFILE_PATH"];` the `-z` parameter is to test if the string is empty. You could use the -n parameter instead to test if the string is null.